# Is there a way to clear all of my TFS pending changes?

Tags: tfs, shelving

If I unshelve a shelveset, the "Pending Changes" toolwindow in Visual Studio will restore the files, the commit comment, and the associated work items I had set up when I shelved.

If I change my mind and decide I'm not ready to work on this shelveset right now -- for example, if I have to drop everything and fix a bug -- is there any way I can clear all of this state at once?

It's easy for me to highlight all the files, right-click, and "Undo". But that only reverts the files; I still have to go in and erase the comment, then switch to the Work Items page, possibly select a different query to make sure I see the work item that I was associated with, and uncheck the box.

Is there a button, menu item, or VS extension that will let me revert the file changes *and* the commit comment *and* the list of work items, all at once, and leave me with a totally clean slate to work on something else?

Comment: Of course, one thing you can do is use different workspaces, or possibly different branches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not at the office to check this out, but it's worth a shot:
 [Shelve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181404.aspx) your changes into a new shelveset, keeping in mind to uncheck the "Preserve pending changes locally".

Comment: Not as clean as I was hoping for, but that works -- I just create a shelveset called "Temp", overwriting if it asks, and next time I'm in the Unshelve dialog, I delete it if I happen to notice it there.

Answer (score 0):

In the next version of Visual Studio it will be a much nicer experience. Check out [the session by Jamie Cool](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-811T) on this topic